# pass 2 parameters via javaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, parameters

I want to send 2 variables when clicking on a button. below is my code

```
$value=$document["rootFolder"];
$value2=$document["uploadSize"];


$_SESSION['rootFolder']=$value;

  echo '<input type="image" src="images/file2.png"  class="btTxt submit" width="85" onclick="myfunc('.$value2.','.$value.')"><b> '.$value . "</b>";
echo "</tr>";

}
```

below is my fuction:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function myfunc(size, fname){ 
                var name=fname;

                var m = parseInt(size);
                var size2 = (m).toString();

        alert(name);
```

Why am I not able to call the 2nd parameter that is `fname`? This works fine when I pass only one parameter that is size.

Comment: The name parameter is most likely text, so you need to wrap it in quotes. This is where creating inline code gets really awkward but you can at least do it like this: `echo "<input ... onclick='myfunc($size, \"$value\")'>...";` It's way better to assign the click handler with JavaScript though.

Comment: Example code: https://ideone.com/z1yGn0

Comment: its not working

Comment: @mishty if that's all the information you're going to tell us, then we cannot help you further. Provide some proper debugging info pleaase. e.g. sample data, the rendered HTML of your function (via the browser's View Source tool), and any errors you are seeing in the browser's Console. These are basic checks you should be making already.

Answer (score 1):

You can alert both values easily:

```js
function myfunc(size, fname) {
  alert(size);
  alert(fname);
}
```

```html
<input type="image" src="images/file2.png" class="btTxt submit" width="85" onclick="myfunc('7','8')">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$value="'".$document["rootFolder"]."'";   //assuming value $document["rootFolder"] = "path/to/root/folder" is string;
$value2=$document["uploadSize"];  //assuming value $document["uploadSize"] = 400 is integer;
```

in your code just changed

```
$value=$document["rootFolder"]; to $value="'".$document["rootFolder"]."'";
```